# how to test if a function was executed when clicking on the button?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-testing-library, react-native-testing-library

I have implemented the component below, which is a card containing information about a product and a button that, when pressed, redirects the user to the details screen.

```
export default function ProductItem(props: ProductItemProps) {
  const {navigate} = useNavigation<any>();

  const {title, id, rating, category, price, thumbnail} = props;

  function navigateToProduct() {
    navigate('Product', {id, title});
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      testID="button-nav"
      style={styles.container}
      activeOpacity={0.75}
      onPress={navigateToProduct}>
      <Image source={{uri: thumbnail, width: 100, height: 100}} />

      <View style={styles.contentInfo}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        <Text>{category}</Text>

        <StarRating rating={rating} />

        <Text style={styles.price}>R${price}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

So far, I've already implemented the test to check the component's rendering, but I need to test if when the button is pressed, the "navigateToProduct" function will be executed.

```
import {fireEvent, render, screen} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import ProductItem from '..';

describe('<ProductItem/>', () => {
  const product = {
    title: 'title-test',
    id: 1,
    rating: 4.5,
    category: 'category-test',
    price: 499,
    thumbnail: 'thumbnail-test',
    description: 'description-test',
    stock: 1,
    brand: 'brand-test',
    images: ['image1-test', 'image2-test'],
  };

  it('Should render correctly product item component', () => {
    render(<ProductItem {...product} />);

    const title = screen.getByText(product.title);
    expect(title).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Should navigate to product screen when button pressed', async () => {
    render(<ProductItem {...product} />);

    const toPress = screen.getByTestId('button-nav');

    fireEvent.press(toPress);
  });
});
```

The whole mock of react navigation "useNavigation" already works. And until then, the tests are all passing. My question is just how can I test if the function is executed. I've tried using spyOn, but I don't know exactly how I can mock this function within my tests. Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Comment: Please add the code of mocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mock function with `jest.fn()` and use `expect(mockFn).toBeCalled()` after firing the key press even to test if the function has been called. Here is an example from the React Native Testing Library docs (swap `toBeCalledWith` and `toBeCalled` for your use case):

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/blob/main/src/__tests__/questionsBoard.test.tsx

```
test('form submits two answers', () => {
  const allQuestions = ['q1', 'q2'];
  const mockFn = jest.fn();

  render(<QuestionsBoard questions={allQuestions} onSubmit={mockFn} />);

  const answerInputs = screen.getAllByLabelText('answer input');

  fireEvent.changeText(answerInputs[0], 'a1');
  fireEvent.changeText(answerInputs[1], 'a2');
  fireEvent.press(screen.getByText('Submit'));

  expect(mockFn).toBeCalledWith({
    1: { q: 'q1', a: 'a1' },
    2: { q: 'q2', a: 'a2' },
  });
});
```